# Calculated date field in Word

Tags: function, ms-word, office365

I want to display the month before, not the actual date.

So for example:

I want to display the 28.2.2021 in a document, that i open today

Thanks in Advance

Comment: To see how to do this and just about everything else you might want to do with dates in Word, check out my **Microsoft Word Date Calculation Tutorial**, at https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38719-microsoft-word-date-calculation-tutorial.html or http://www.gmayor.com/downloads.htm#Third_party
In particular, look at the item titled *Calculate a day, date, month and year, using n months delay*. Do read the document's introductory material.

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It would be better posted in Super User because it is not exactly a programming question *(although Word fields can feel like programming)*. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Nevertheless, macropod provided you with the best answer you will find anywhere on this question. If you need followup, consider reposting this in Stack Overflow where it is on-topic. https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word